# Memory Optimized Database recovery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, in-memory-database, database-restore

There's situation when my database(with memory optimized tables) has gone into 'Recovery Pending' state.  I tried to put it into

```
emergency mode-->Single User Mode--> DBCC CHECKDB(<DBName>)--->set it online--->Multiuser mode.
```

But I am facing below error message while doing ONLINE mode.

> Msg 5181, Level 16, State 5, Line 9 Could not restart database
>   "DBName". Reverting to the previous status. Msg 5069, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 9 ALTER DATABASE statement failed. Msg 41316, Level 23, State
>   3, Line 3395 Restore operation failed for database 'DBName' with
>   internal error code '0x0000000a'

I tried to check SQL error Log file and there's below message.

> [ERROR] Database ID: [6] ''. Failed to load XTP checkpoint. Error
>   code: 0x88000001.
>   (d:\b\s2\sources\sql\ntdbms\hekaton\sqlhost\sqlmin\hkhostdb.cpp : 5288
>   - 'HkHostRecoverDatabaseHelper::ReportAndRaiseFailure')

And Rebuilding log file for Memory Optimized database is also not supported. Does anyone know familiar with such error?

Comment: Since 2016 RTM there's been a lot of bugfixes with in-memory OLTP, some for quite fundamental issues. The most recent version of 2016, as of writing, is 2016 SP2 CU1; if you're not already on that, I'd recommend upgrading before you proceed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Doing this will resolve my current issue?

Comment: I would be a fool if I promised you that. My point is that if you have the opportunity to upgrade, you should, if only to bypass all the other known issues, and possibly get a version that can recover your DB. My experience is that in-memory OLTP databases that fail to come online are often "lost forever", as in, restoring from backup (possibly after dropping the whole database) is the only way to make actual progress, because `DBCC CHECKDB` knows little to nothing about them.